# How can I formalize this idea to prove that there exists a surjection between $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow P(\mathbb{N})$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $x\in P(\mathbb{N})$ a set is charachterized by the elements it contains. Because all elements must be in $\mathbb{N}$ the elements can be ordered. And this order charachterizes the subset. I.e forall elements there exists a injection $f$ between $P(\mathbb{N})$ and $\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}$ (How can I prove this). and also if it is a finite set I will mark it with an infinite Array of $9$

Then forall $x\in f(P(\mathbb{N}))$ there exists a injection $g$ to $\mathbb{R}$ again which assaigns the sequence to a decimalnumber given by $0.(\text{sequence})$ (How can I prove this)? (Every element of the sequence is seperated by a 0) not to confuse between $0.23$ and $0,203$

I need some help to finish the proof please help

Comment: Do you understand what the maps $f$ and $g$ are? Can you write them down for simple examples?

Comment: Also, I'm concerned about the map $g$, even with that added $0$. Seems like $2,3,0,0,...$ and $203, 0, 0, ...$ will map to the same decimal number.

Comment: I cannot understand your first sentence.  I assume that $P(\mathbb{N})$ means "power set of the natural numbers" but I am not sure that is what you mean

Comment: @NathanielMayer  You are right but this Problem can be solved by determining whether the set is finite or not. If it is finite then I will map it to $\mathbb{N}^z$ where $z$ is the cardinality of the set

Comment: @Michael yes thats what I meant

Comment: Or I can also say if the set $x$ is finite then for $g(x)$  I will fill in the blank spots with $9$ instead of $0$

Comment: @New2Math How does that fix the problem? You're trying to come up with one consistently defined map, first $f: P(\mathbb{N}) \to \mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ and then $g:\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Filling with $9$ will just create the same problem with different inputs.

Comment: I don't see an easy fix to make your function $g$ injective. I suggest you look at replacing $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ by $2^\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: I see that's true

Comment: I still cannot understand the first sentence...is there missing punctuation?

Comment: I was trying to find an injective map $f:P(\mathbb{N})\rightarrow \mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}$ and then another injective map $\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ but I failed. My main Goal was to find an injective map $P(\mathbb{N})\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ where $P(\mathbb{N})$ is the powerset of $\mathbb{N}$  I took an element of the powerset which is a subset and said that a set can be charachterized by the Elements it contains. By saying that I was refering to the subset $x$ I just picked, which is an element of the powerset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe may have some pitfalls. Instead, try $f: P(\mathbb{N}) \to \{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$ sending a subset to a sequence of $0$'s and $1$'s with the $n$-th spot in the sequence marking whether or not $n$ is an element of your subset.

The second map $g$ should be less problematic from this domain.

Comment: I was just writing a comment About the same idea however there is something that makes me hesitate. If I do it like you told me than I get for the set $\{1,3\}=x, f(x)=101$. But if you finish this thought then you can actually describe **every** subset with a natrual number. But this cannot be true because there exist no surjection between $P(\mathbb{N})$ and $\mathbb{N}$. Do you see what I mean?

Comment: No, $f(x)$ is an infinite sequence ending in all $0$'s. Infinite subsets will go to infinite sequences that don't end in all $0$'s. These don't associate with natural numbers.

Comment: I succeded to verify that $f$ is injective. $f:P(\mathbb{N})\rightarrow \{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ was defined as $f(x)=z$ where $z(n)\begin{cases} =1 & \mbox{if }n\in x \\ =0 & \mbox{if }n\notin x\end{cases}$. Now assuming $(*)f(x) = f(y)\wedge x\neq y$ implies $\exists r\in\mathbb{N}: e\in x \wedge r\notin y \vee r\notin x \wedge r\notin y$. Without loss $r\in x \wedge  r\notin y\Rightarrow 1=(f(x))(r)\overset{*}{=}(f(y))(r)=0$ which is a contradiction therefore $f(x)=f(y)\Rightarrow x=y $

Comment: But I have Problems to find an injective map $g:\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. The Problem was not find the map but to Show that it is injective. Note that $x\in\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}\iff x:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \{0,1\}$. So $x$ is a function mapping from $\mathbb{N}$ to the set $\{0,1\}$. Now I say $g(x)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\frac{1}{10^n}x(n)$. Now I want to Show if $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\frac{1}{10^n}x(n)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\frac{1}{10^n}y(n)\Rightarrow x(n)=y(n),\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: I don't know how I can Show it I have experimented a Little bit by contraposition $\exists n_0\in\mathbb{N}:x(n_0)\neq y(n_0)\wedge \sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\frac{1}{10^n}x(n)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\frac{1}{10^n}y(n)$, but I didn' t get far. Please help me to Show that $g$ as I have defined it in here is injective. The Thing is it is obvious if there is one Digit in the decimal which is different from the other decimal then the difference can not be Zero but it is technically (at least for me) hard to prove.

Comment: I could solve the issue

Comment: I think you're getting a bit too wrapped up in definitions, which is a common problem for new proof-writers. A proof is an explanation, so start by thinking about why this is true. Suppose you have two decimals with only 0's and 1's in the expansion, one of which starts like $0.1x_1x_2x_3...$ and the other starts like $0.0y_1y_2y_3...$ Can they possibly be equal? No, the one starting with a $1$ must be greater (why? fill this in)

Comment: I had the same idea but a guy told me that it is important to give the proof because if I would Chose my function $g(x)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\frac{1}{2^n}x(n)$ then the function would be not injective anymore, for reference see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3117433/show-that-a-map-is-injective-g-0-1-mathbbn-rightarrow-mathbbr

Comment: Sure, but what I wrote is a proof. It's just not as rigid. Proofs are exposition. They're not written in symbolic formal language, they're written in English. You want to be precise and correct, but you don't need to agonize over rigid forms. The argument I gave above would have caught the error with the binary expansion, because 0.10000.... = 0.01111... = 1/2 in binary. My argument is that a *decimal* starting with 1 is at least 1/10, but a decimal starting with 0 (and using only 0's and 1's) is at most 1/90.