# Show that a map is injective $g:\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis

I have Problems to find an injective map $g:\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. The Problem was not find the map but to Show that it is injective. Note that $x\in\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}\iff x:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \{0,1\}$. So $x$ is a function mapping from $\mathbb{N}$ to the set $\{0,1\}$. Now I say $g(x)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\frac{1}{10^n}x(n)$. Now I want to Show if $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\frac{1}{10^n}x(n)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\frac{1}{10^n}y(n)\Rightarrow x(n)=y(n),\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$. I don't know how I can Show it I have experimented a Little bit by contraposition $\exists n_0\in\mathbb{N}:x(n_0)\neq y(n_0)\wedge \sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\frac{1}{10^n}x(n)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\frac{1}{10^n}y(n)$, but I didn' t get far. Please help me to Show that $g$ as I have defined it in here is injective. The Thing is it is obvious if there is one Digit in the decimal which is different from the other decimal then the difference can not be Zero but it is technically (at least for me) hard to prove.

Comment: Contraposition is a good starting point. Make your life easier by using the well-ordering principle and pick the least $n_0$ such that $x(n_0)\neq y(n_0)$. Then both series are equal for indices less than $n_0$, so try to show that $\sum_{n>n_0}\frac{x(n)-y(n)}{10^n}$ cannot exceed $\frac{x(n_0)-y(n_0)}{10^{n_0}}$ in absolute value (assume $x(n_0)>y(n_0)$ wlog for the sake of simplicity) and then you have a contradiction as the series need be equal (hint: geometric series). Also, what you call "obvious" is actually the crux; think about why the map is not injective if you replace $10$ by $2$.

Comment: Thank you that solved the Problem can you have a glance over my calculations? To Show: $\sum_{n>n_0}\frac{1}{10^n}<\frac{1}{10^{n_0}}$. Because $\sum_{n>n_0}\frac{1}{10^n}=\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{10}}-\sum_{n=0}^{n_0}\frac{1}{10^n}=\frac{10}{9}-\frac{1-\frac{1}{10^{n_0+1}}}{1-\frac{1}{10}}=\frac{\frac{90}{10}-9+\frac{9}{10^{n_0+1}}}{\frac{81}{10}}=\frac{90}{10^{n_0+1}\cdot 81}\overset{!}{<}\frac{1}{10^{n_0}}\iff   90 < \frac{10^{n_0+1}\cdot 81}{10^{n_0}}=10\cdot 81= 810 \square$

Comment: concerning your second Question witht the same calculations we would get the same result for $g(x)$ and $g(y)$ if $x=100...$ and $y=011...$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the properties of geometric series, we have that $10^{-k} > \sum_{i > k} 10^{-i}$.

Suppose $g(x) = g(y)$ but for some $n$ we had that $x(n) \neq y(n)$ but for all $k < n$ we have $x(k) = y(k)$. Suppose wlog that $x(n) = 1$ and $y(n) = 0$. Then we would have that

$$ \sum_{i \geq n} (x(i))^{-i} > \sum_{i \geq n} (y(i))^{-i}$$

since (again, by the properties of the sum of a geometric series)

$$ \sum_{i \geq n} (x(i))^{-i} \leq \frac{1}{9}$$
$$ \sum_{i \geq n} (y(i))^{-i} \leq \frac{1}{9}$$